# Find all times that follow a pattern

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, date

Your job is write a program that prints all times (in the format HH:MM, 24 hours) that follow any of the following patterns:

- Hours equal to minutes, e.g. 22:22,01:01
- Hours equal to reverse minutes, e.g. 10:01, 01:10, 22:22
- Sequences, that match H:MM, or HH:MM, always printed with HH:MM. E.g. 00:12, 01:23, 23:45, 03:45, etc (always a single step between digits)

Rules:

- You may choose any language you like
- You cannot print repeated times
- One time per line, following the order of the day
- The winner will be chosen in February 5.

PS: this is my first question, it might have some inconsistencies. Feel free to edit.

PS2: Here is the expected 44 solutions (already presented by Josh and primo, Thanks!)

```
00:00
00:12
01:01
01:10
01:23
02:02
02:20
02:34
03:03
03:30
03:45
04:04
04:40
04:56
05:05
05:50
06:06
07:07
08:08
09:09
10:01
10:10
11:11
12:12
12:21
12:34
13:13
13:31
14:14
14:41
15:15
15:51
16:16
17:17
18:18
19:19
20:02
20:20
21:12
21:21
22:22
23:23
23:32
23:45
```

Comment: I'd expect that `3:45` is written `03:45` in `HH:MM` format and thus not a sequence.

Comment: right! I miss that in the examples

Comment: I'm confused. Is 03:45 supposed to be a sequence or not? :)

Comment: yes, zeros at the begining do not count. I know, this complicates a bit, sorry for that ;)

Comment: does `13:57` count as a sequence? What about `6:54`? On the same note, `6:42` needs to be decided upon, too.

Comment: Do times with only a single digit that's not a leading zero such as `00:01` count as a sequence?

Comment: @JanDvorak `13:57` is not a sequence (at least not with "step 1"). `6:34` is a reversed sequence, I didn't include those in the patterns, I don't think is a good idea to change now that there are already answers. Also `6:42` isn't a sequence.

Comment: @Josh I didn't quite understand your question. But I don't consider `00:01` a sequence

Comment: @RSFalcon7 So only some leading zeroes are ignored? Which ones? 23:45, 02:34, 00:23, 00:02 would seem to be similar cases.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson sequences are only valid when they start in the hours and finish on the seconds

Comment: @RSFalcon7 Maybe you should clarify `zeros at the beginning do not count` in the question then. Does that mean that 00:12 is a sequence but 00:23 is not?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson right, I will clarify. Thanks

Comment: I think it is clearer now.

Comment: @RSFalcon7 I dont see the sequence listed but is this a valid sequence? `01:02`, `02:04`, `03:06`,..,`06:12`,..,`10:20`, `20:40`, you get the message I guess, basicly `minutes = (hours*2)`

Comment: @TeunPronk No, none of then are valid sequences. Sequences must have a step 1, between **digits**.

Comment: @RSFalcon7 I couldnt really figure it out if `03:21` reversed sequences were allowed or not. if they are allowed, seeing that `00:12` is a sequence does that make `00:21` or `00:10` also a sequence?

Comment: @TeunPronk reversed sequences are not allowed.

Comment: 1 Day to the deadline :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Golfscript (<s>82</s> 72)**

Still very much a beginner, but there was no GS answer, so... :)

```
24,{'0'\+-2>..+\.-1%+}%5,{'0'7,{+}/>4<.(;0\+}%|{2=54<},$);{2/~':'\++}%n*
```

Comment: PHP isn't going to be able to beat that.

Comment: And C definitely won't be able to beat that.

Answer (score 4):

### C, 118 (initially 136)

```
h,m;main(){h<24&&main(m>57?m=0,h++:h==m|h==m%10*10+m/10|m-12==h*11|h==m-22&!(~-m++%11)&&printf("%02d:%02d\n",h,m-1));}
```

An iterative version with 119 characters:

```
h;main(m){for(;h<24;h++)for(m=0;m<57;m++)h==m|h==m%10*10+m/10|m-12==h*11|h==m-22&!(~-m%11)&&printf("%02d:%02d\n",h,m);}
```

A big thanks to @squeamish ossifrage !

Comment: It is not ordered :(

Comment: Missed that.  Fixing my solution!

Comment: Should be good now.

Comment: I think you are missing the line `23:45`.

Comment: Fixed at the cost of 8 characters.

Comment: Looks like sequences that start with `0` are supposed to be included too.

Comment: My solution outputs those (such as `02:34`).  The rule `m-12==h*11` catches them.

Comment: You could replace `100*h+m==1234||100*h+m==2345` with `((m-h)==22)&&!((m-1)%11)` (maybe even with fewer brackets)

Comment: Jackpot!  Back down to 128 characters.  Thanks!

Comment: This would seem to find fewer sequences than the Python answer, some clarification may be needed.

Comment: My understanding was to not include sequences that only have a single digit such as `00:01`.  I will post on the original question for clarification.

Comment: the first `for` loop can be reduced to `for(;h<24;h++)` to save one char and the second `for` loop can be reduced to `for(m=0;m<60;)` and use `m++` instead of `m` in the `printf` argument. Besides, if you declare `m` outside `main` (i.e. together with `h`), then it will also be initialized to zero and you can save 3 chars in the second `for` loop.

Comment: @ace thanks for the first hint, I forgot to remove the `h` from the first `for` loop.  But, the other two optimizations would break my code.  If I put `m++` in the `printf` call, how will the variable be incremented in the case none of the `if` statements are triggered?  And if I don't initialize `m` in the second `for` loop it will not be correctly set to zero after the hour count is looped from `0` to `1`.

Comment: @Josh Oh right... Didn't thought about that, sorry.

Comment: Dropped 2 more characters by replacing my `if` statement with a boolean condition, but it's going to be hard to beat the newly posted PHP solution.

Answer (score 4):

### PHP - 93 bytes

```
<?for(;24>$h;)@ereg(+$h=&date(i,$i).$m=date(s,$i++),"0123456$h$h".strrev($h))&&print"$h:$m
";
```

This will find patterns like `02:34`, but will not find patterns like `00:23` or `00:02`. If i understand the OP's clarifications in the comments, this is correct.

Prints a total of 44 results:

```
00:00
00:12
01:01
01:10
01:23
02:02
02:20
02:34
03:03
03:30
03:45
04:04
04:40
04:56
05:05
05:50
06:06
07:07
08:08
09:09
10:01
10:10
11:11
12:12
12:21
12:34
13:13
13:31
14:14
14:41
15:15
15:51
16:16
17:17
18:18
19:19
20:02
20:20
21:12
21:21
22:22
23:23
23:32
23:45
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python (178)**

```
s=sorted
for i in[x for x in['%04d'%i for i in range(2400)if i/10%10<6]if s(x[:2])==s(x[2:])or len({i-ord(y)for i,y in enumerate(x.lstrip('0'))})==1]:print'%2s:%2s'%(i[:2],i[2:])
```

Stripping all leading zeroes before sequences gives 57 results in total.

Answer (score 2):

### APL (90)

```
F←{,'ZI2'⎕FMT⍵}⋄↑⊃¨{(F⍺),':',F⍵}/¨Z/⍨{(⍺=⍵)∨(≡/0 1⌽∘F¨⍺⍵)∨∧/¯1=2-/⍎¨(⍕⍺),F⍵}/¨Z←,1-⍨⍳24 60
```

Comment: That's it. I'm off to make a dialect of perl where every keyword and most functions are a single character. +1, btw ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript - 171 chars (5/2/14) !

```
for(h='00';+h<24;h=(++h<10?'0':'')+h)for(m='00';+m<60;m=(++m<10?'0':'')+m)if(h[1]+h[0]==m||h==m||+m[1]-m[0]==1&&+m[0]-h[1]==1&&(!+h[0]||+h[1]-h[0]==1))console.log(h+':'+m)
```

I seriously am getting the hang of golfing. If I look back from now, I have cut down almost 30 chars ! [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/EkEbodI/10/edit).

### Ungolfed (and commented) :

```
// Note: +'string' is same as 'parseInt(string, 10)'
// Also, this code is not the shortest one, I have purposely made this code longer for
// understanding purposes

for(h = '0'; +h < 24; h = +h + 1 + '') //initialize h(our), loop while it's less than 24
{                                      // increase it by 1 and cast back to string
    for(m = '0'; +m < 60; m= +m + 1 + '') // intialize m(inute), loop while < 60
    {                                  // increase it by 1 and cast back to string
        if(h.length < 2) h = 0 + h;    // if it is '9', convert to '09'
        if(m.length < 2) m = 0 + m;    // if it is '9', convert to '09'

        // Tests for printing
        if(h[0] === m[1] && m[0] === h[1] ||
           h === m ||
           +m[1] - +m[0] === 1 && +m[0] - +h[1] === 1 && (+h[0] === 0 || +h[1] -+ h[0] === 1))
        console.log(h + ':' + m);  // print
    } // inner loop end
}     // outer loop end
```

#### 187 chars (Old) (4/2/14)

```
for(h='00';+h<24;h=(+h<9?'0':'')+(+h+1))for(m='00';+m<60;m=(+m<9?'0':'')+(+m+1))if(h[0]==m[1]&&m[0]==h[1]||h==m||+m[1]-m[0]==1&&+m[0]-h[1]==1&&(!+h[0]||+h[1]-h[0]==1))console.log(h+':'+m)
```

Little bit of experimenting, and lot improvement (9 chars) :) [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/EkEbodI/9/edit?js,console)

#### 196 chars (Old) (3/2/14)

```
for(h='00';+h<24;h=(+h<9?'0':'')+(+h+1))for(m='00';+m<60;m=(+m<9?'0':'')+(+m+1))if(h[0]==m[1]&&m[0]==h[1]||h==m||+m[1]-m[0]==1&&+m[0]-h[1]==1&&(!+h[0]||+h[1]-h[0]==1))console.log(h+':'+m)
```

Sat down with a fresh mind and improved it a lot, a one liner :) [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/EkEbodI/4/edit).

#### 208 chars (Old) (2/2/14)

```
for(h='0';+h<24;h=+h+1+''){for(m='0';+m<60;m=+m+1+''){if(h.length<2)h=0+h
if(m.length<2)m=0+m
if(h[0]==m[1]&&m[0]==h[1]||h==m||+m[1]-+m[0]==1&&+m[0]-+h[1]==1&&(+h[0]==0||+h[1]-+h[0]==1))console.log(h+':'+m)}}
```

---

Gives exactly the 44 required times (each in new line)

Will keep improving my code.

I would highly appreciate any feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Updated Recently !!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 248 characters

Guess I'm a little late and not very good as well, but finally, got my first codegolf thing to share:

I decided to only support real sequences like 01:23 and 23:45, not 00:12. Anyway, I bet theres plenty to do better, so please go ahead and share a comment with me.

```
import itertools as t
s=sorted
r=range
i=int
d='%02d'
e=d+':'+d
print([e%(i(a[0]),i(a[1])) for a in t.product([d% x for x in r(0,24)], [d% x for x in r(0,60)]) if s(a[0])==s(a[1]) or list(a[0]+a[1])==[str(x) for x in r(i(a[0][0]),i(a[1][-1])+1)]])
```

Got the very descriptive version along with it on my [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=eBBrnPCF)

Answer (score 0):

## Delphi

Still working on it but this is what i have so far.
It works, but im sure its possible to get it shorter.
**Edit:** Prints 48 times.

### Without indent 422 characters

```
uses System.SysUtils,DateUtils;var t:TTime;a,b,c,d:integer;s:string;begin t:=StrToTime('00:01');while t<StrToTime('23:59')do begin s:=FormatDateTime('hhnn',t);a:=StrToInt(s[1]);b:=StrToInt(s[2]);c:=StrToInt(s[3]);d:=StrToInt(s[4]);if((a+1=b)and(b+1=c)and(c+1=d))or((a=0)and(b+1=c)and(c+1=d))or((a=0)and(b=0)and(c+1=d))or((a=d)and(b=c))or((a=c)and(b=d))then WriteLn(FormatDateTime('hh:nn',t));t:=IncMinute(t)end;ReadLn;end.
```

### With indent 557characters

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, DateUtils;

var
  t:TTime;
  a,b,c,d:integer;
  s:string;
begin
  t:=StrToTime('00:01');
  while t<StrToTime('23:59')do
  begin
    s:=FormatDateTime('hhnn',t);
    a:=StrToInt(s[1]);
    b:=StrToInt(s[2]);
    c:=StrToInt(s[3]);
    d:=StrToInt(s[4]);
    if((a+1=b) and (b+1=c) and (c+1=d)) or
      ((a=0) and (b+1=c) and (c+1=d)) or
      ((a=0) and (b=0) and (c+1=d)) or
      ((a=d) and (b=c)) or ((a=c) and (b=d)) then
      WriteLn(FormatDateTime('hh:nn',t));
    t:=IncMinute(t)
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

## q (116)

```
distinct{t:string 00:00+x;$[(t[0 1]in(t[3 4];t[4 3]))|all 1=1_deltas{"I"$x}each t[0 1 3 4];t;"00:00"]}each til 1440
```

Increments 00:00 to 23:59, casts to string, then check (test 1 or 2) or 3

Output:

```
("00:00";"01:01";"01:10";"01:23";"02:02";"02:20";"03:03";"03:30";"04:04";"04:40";"05:05";"05:50";"06:06";"07:07";"08:08";"09:09";"10:01";"10:10";"11:11";"12:12";"12:21";"12:34";"13:13";"13:31";"14:14";"14:41";"15:15";"15:51";"16:16";"17:17";"18:18";"19:19";"20:02";"20:20";"21:12";"21:21";"22:22";"23:23";"23:32";"23:45")
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP - <strike>56</strike> <strike>39</strike> 31 bytes

```
<? http_redirect("goo.gl/W2M5mo")?>
```

It doesn't bend the rules in any way. You need the pecl_http module installed and short_open_tag set to "1" in php.ini.

Comment: +1, if nothing else for sneakiness, although Octave beats it at 38 characters `disp(urlread('http://bit.ly/1fzhb3C'))` :)

Comment: ...although you should probably consider the custom designed static HTML you're loading a part of the source code, otherwise a static file would do (and equally not be counted...?)